# Query working days from calendar in CRM 2015

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, crm

I have created a calendar (working days) for a resource (e.g. facility). How can I get a list or at least ranges of working days directly from the database?

All I have found so far are Calendar and CalendarRule views. The problem with the CalendarRule is that the rule is written with a pattern like

```
"FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR"
```

I can not find a way to use this in SQL query.

Comment: As in a querying your created calendar? Or are you asking if there is an in built calendar?

Comment: Querying the created calendar. I need a list of working days for a specific facility.

Comment: Whats a facility? Post up your table structures, how are we meant to know what your tables are without your telling us? Also put up some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming working days are `mon` to `fri` and your `calendar` table is linked to the `resources` table by `calendar.workingdays = resources.daysworked`, if not obviously adjust them to suit.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(dow FROM timestamp (to_timestamp(c.workingdays), "YYYY-MM-DD")), r.facility
FROM Calendar c
LEFT JOIN Resources r ON c.workingdays = r.daysworked
WHERE EXTRACT(dow FROM timestamp (to_timestamp(c.workingdays, "YYYY-MM-DD"))
NOT IN (0,6)
```